# Position fixed with bootstrap columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sibdebar which I want always to appear on the top of the screen when the user scroll down and get to it, so I use this thread for help:
[Make element fixed on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484084/make-element-fixed-on-scroll)

Problem is, when I scroll down something with the width is going wrong.
First is OK:
[image]

But when I scroll down:
[image]

The code:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="dynamic-sidebar">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('single_post_sidebar');?>
                <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                        var elementPosition = $('#dynamic-sidebar').offset();           
                        $(window).scroll(function(){
                            if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
                                $('#dynamic-sidebar').css('position','fixed').css('top','0');
                            } else {
                                $('#dynamic-sidebar').css('position','static');

                            }    
                        });
                    }); 
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 single-post-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
           </div>
 </div>
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Is it col-3 and col-9 design?

Comment: Yes, but that's inside col-sm-9 parent..

Comment: Inside col-9 parent make two div with col-9 col-3 and put fixed div into col-3 and let other things same or make  this col-3 fixed always.

Comment: Didn't really get you.. If i will make this col-sm-3 fixed always it will get to the top of the screen regardless the scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the example below,I have just added style "right:0" and "position:fixed" to the col-3 inside col-9.

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-top:200px">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <!--Put here your long paragraph-->
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                <br/><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <br /><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pull-right" style="position:fixed; right: 0">
                <ul class="list-group ">
                    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>                      
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did it, now it looks like this when scroll down: http://i.imgur.com/qvscFTQ.jpg... Still didn't manage to solve this.

Comment: It seems all good with attached image link, what's the problem now?

Comment: It just move the sidebar to the right overlaps the .contianer limits, like this: http://i.imgur.com/nvLA2Km.jpg?1