# resize and scroll event together in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make element fixed at the time of scrolling. I have got some solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484084/make-element-fixed-on-scroll). I have picked one solution (@Beat Richartz's solution) and tried to achieve it by binding this two event together like this way:

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function (e) {
   // code
});
```

But, it seems that it's not working properly at the time of resizing. At time of resizing, it woks well only If I refresh the page. How to bind this event together?

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eeqq9/42/)

Answer (score 0):

Create separate function of your logic and call same function as parameter on different events.You can try below code

```
    var myFunction = function() {
         //code
     }

$(window)
    .resize(myFunction)
    .scroll(myFunction)
```