# How to properly calculate window screen height to fit an element inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am attempting to set the height for `#blue_square` inside the `divTwo` div . I'm calculating the height using jquery:

```
$("#blue_square").css("top", $(window).height() / 2 - 90)
```

This code works on big screens(like desktop) but on smaller screens (like laptop,tablet, mobile) this code does not work.

The problem I am seeing is that my `blue_square` CSS from `divTwo` is somehow starting on from `blueBackground` div. Here is a snap shot: [example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuNea.png)

I want the CSS for `#blue_square` to only apply within the `divTwo` not outside of it. Why is the "blue sqaure" diagram starting on blueBackground and not from within divTwo? I am trying to make it look like this: [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m4SQ.png) .

I am thinking that I am miscalculating the height of #blue_square.  Any ways to fix this?

```
<div class="blueBackground"></div>

<div class="divTwo">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10">   
        <div id="blue_square" style="top: 310px;"></div>
    </div>   
</div>


.divTwo{
    position: relative;
}

#blue_square{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 370px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent;
}

$("#blue_square").css("top", $(window).height() / 2 - 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your usage of fixed position for #blue_square could be why the #blue_square is starting from top of blueBackground div not of the divTwo div

but you can try using this jQuery `.height()` method to get the height of the div and then use the `.css()` method to set the height of the element based on that value.

there you go:

```
var divHeight = $('.divTwo').height();
$('#blue_square').css('height', divHeight);
```

This will set the height of the #blue_square to match the height of the divTwo div.

Comment: I am using position: fixed because I want the blue_square to stay in the same place while I scroll the page. But I was hoping it would stay within the `.divTwo`.

Comment: try this `#blue_square{ position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); z-index: 9; width: 370px; box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent; }`

Comment: This CSS does not work in my case, because when I am scrolling the page, I am not seeing the blue_square. This is why it should have position fixed, so even when I am scrolling the page I can still the blue_square

Answer (score 0):

You could use this calculation:

```
const blueTop = $(".blueBackground").height() + $(window).height() / 2 - 90;
$("#blue_square").css("top",  blueTop);
```

However, if the blue background is as large, or larger, then the window it will not show the blue block at all. If you want the blue block to appear after the user starts scrolling past the blue background you will need to use Javascript for that. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484084/make-element-fixed-on-scroll))

Comment: Any examples on how I would do this through JavaScript? That is the part I am confused about.

Comment: You'll need to add a scroll listener and then change the styles of the fixed element after a certain amount of scrolling. I added an example link to my answer.